# VS code's Python debugger and its ability to show contained items in iterables or mappings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I noticed that the debugger's ability to show what items are held in a mapping or iterable only works for some types but not others. Is there a way to "explain" to the debugger that you want the individual items to show for a certain mapping / iterable?

Here's a couple of examples:

[image]

The `mappingproxy` is missing the nested items (`'a': 1` and `'b': 2` here). This makes it infeasible to browse its values when populated by a few 10s or 100s of items.

Here's another example:
[image]

You can see that the debugger knows how to traverse the values using the iterator, why doesn't it print them as nested items when expanded?